# JavaScript document.getElementById().value logs empty value

Tags: javascript

I want the value of the text input logged to the console but when I open the page the console.log() is empty. Why is this?

```js
<input type="text" id="word"/>

//JavaScript
var newWord = document.getElementById("word").value;
console.log(newWord);
```

Comment: The `<input>` is empty on pageload

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: Have you abbreviated your example?  You need to respond to an event like `onchange` or add a button with an `onclick` event handler to tell the browser when to run your JavaScript, otherwise if it runs immediately, there will be no value in the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure to add an event handler.

Add an onchange event listener to input element.

```js
function func() {
var newWord = document.getElementById("word").value;
console.log(newWord);

}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="word" onchange='func()'/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to enter a value to your input or add a default value

```
<input type="text" id="word" value="Hello"/>

var newWord = document.getElementById("word").value;
console.log(newWord);
```

This will log the value

Answer (score 1):

Use [`.addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to run a function when a [`change`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event) event is  fired - This will run your function whenever the value  in the input is updated and the focus is removed from the input box

```js
document.getElementById('word').addEventListener('change', function () {
  let newWord = this.value;
  
  console.log(newWord);
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="word"/>
```

Or, you could use the [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event) event, which will fire as soon as the input is changed

```js
document.getElementById('word').addEventListener('input', function () {
  let newWord = this.value;
  
  console.log(newWord);
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="word"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot get your question, but according to my understanding, you need to use a function to get the value of input box, when an event occurs. here is the code something like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>A function is triggered when the user is pressing a key in the input field.</p>

<input type="text" id="myinput" onkeypress="myFunction()">

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
var x = document.getElementById('myinput').value;
  document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = x;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```